# VS Code: Ctrl + N does not work despite a correct keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

When in VS Code, pressing `CTRL+n` no longer does anything. However, when I look at the keyboard shortcuts, it indicates that `CTRL+n` is supposed to open a new untitled text file.

[image]

When I attempt to edit the entry to see if that would make a difference, it won't allow me to enter `CTRL+n` but it will allow a plethora of other key combinations.

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

PS I can go into the file menu to open a new untitled text file.

---

### Troubleshooting Keybindings

```
2023-06-24 16:36:42.482 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-06-24 16:36:42.483 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-06-24 16:36:42.483 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-06-24 16:36:42.484 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-06-24 16:36:42.484 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
```

The above chunk repeats itself many times before pressing `CTRL+N`

```
2023-06-24 16:36:43.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-06-24 16:36:43.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-06-24 16:36:43.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-06-24 16:36:43.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-06-24 16:36:43.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-06-24 16:36:43.905 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
2023-06-24 16:36:56.203 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-06-24 16:36:56.203 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-06-24 16:36:56.204 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-06-24 16:36:56.204 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-06-24 16:36:56.204 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-06-24 16:36:56.474 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-06-24 16:36:56.474 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+A
2023-06-24 16:36:56.475 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.selectAll, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2023-06-24 16:36:56.475 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyA, keyCode: 65, key: a
2023-06-24 16:36:56.475 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyA, keyCode: 31 ('A')
2023-06-24 16:36:56.475 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+A
2023-06-24 16:36:56.476 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.selectAll, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2023-06-24 16:36:56.476 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.selectAll.
```

---

### Help: About

```
Version: 1.79.2 (user setup)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

---

### Keybinding.json

```
{ "key": "ctrl+n",                "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" }
```

---

### Other Interesting Info

To see what would happen, I changed the new untitled file shortcut to `CTRL+T CRTL+T` and it works.

If this is useful, in shortcuts, I cannot manually create the following shortcuts: `CTRL+O` `CTRL+P` and `CTRL+N`

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: possibly related issue tickets: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79468, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54605

Comment: The problem persists when I load `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled`.  Thanks for the heads-up on the issue ticket.

Comment: ...weird. you get KeyA even when pressing KeyN?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: Sorry, @starball, the `a key` was because I hit `CTRL+A` to copy all the output. It occurred after I attempted `CTRL+N`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-windows-keybindings what keyboard layout do you have? btw, if you end up creating an issue ticket following the troubleshooting steps, please [edit] a link to it into your question post here.

Comment: I have a standard QWERTY keyboard

Comment: To see what would happen, I changed the `new untitled file` shortcut to `CTRL+T CRTL+T` and it works.

Comment: If this is useful, in shortcuts, I cannot manually create the following shortcuts: `CTRL+O` ` CTRL+P` and `CTRL+N`

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.